# Creating a 1:2 relationship between a principal entity and 2 dependent entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Working with EF Core 7, how do I define the following relationship?

```
public class PrincipalEntity
{
    [Key, StringLength(300)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public TheKey PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public TheKey SecondaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class TheKey
{
    [StringLength(200)]        
    public string PrincipalEntityName { get; set; } // foreign key

    public string Value { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Such that my `PrincipalEntity` is related to two instances of the dependent entity (`Key`).

I would prefer to have individual properties `PrimaryKey` and `SecondaryKey` in the `PrincipalEntity` rather than a `IEnumerable<TheKey> keys` property.

Comment: Why does the relationship you defined not suffice?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PrincipalEntity> PrincipalEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TheKey> TheKeys { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PrincipalEntity>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Name);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PrincipalEntity>()
            .HasOne(p => p.PrimaryKey)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<TheKey>(k => k.PrincipalEntityName)
            .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PrincipalEntity>()
            .HasOne(p => p.SecondaryKey)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<TheKey>(k => k.PrincipalEntityName)
            .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TheKey>()
            .HasKey(k => new { k.PrincipalEntityName, k.Value });
    }
}

public class PrincipalEntity
{
    [Key, StringLength(300)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public TheKey PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    public TheKey SecondaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class TheKey
{

    public string PrincipalEntityName { get; set; } // foreign key

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

In this setup:

`PrincipalEntity` class contains two navigation properties (`PrimaryKey` and `SecondaryKey`) each representing a one-to-one relationship with `TheKey`.

The `OnModelCreating` method configures these relationships using the Fluent API.

The `HasKey` method is used to specify the primary key for both entities.

`HasForeignKey` method is used to specify the foreign key relationship between `PrincipalEntity` and `TheKey`.

`.IsRequired(false)` is used because the relationship is optional, considering that you mentioned individual properties `PrimaryKey` and `SecondaryKey` in `PrincipalEntity` rather than a collection.

With these configurations, Entity Framework Core will recognize the relationship between `PrincipalEntity` and `TheKey`, and you can work with them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, the `Add-Migration` step didn't give any errors, but table definition for `PrincipalEntity` is very weird: there's a column `PrimaryKeyPrincipalEntityName` (`nvarchar(300)`) and `PrimaryKeyValue` (`nvarchar(300)`). There's no mention of SecondaryKey

Comment: This doesn't work: the relationship defined 2nd gets ignored. If I put the relationship mapping for `SecondaryKey` first, I get the columns `SecondaryKeyPrincipalEntityName` & `SecondaryKeyValue` (so that `PrimaryKey` is now ignored)